# gnuplot create fenceplot from multiple line graphs

Tags: gnuplot

I have data for three line graphs.  How would I go about creating a fenceplot to represent them all?

```
8 12
6 18
3 4
10 17

14 24
8 22
4 15
6 18

17 26
7 18
2 16
4 12
```

```
splot 'test.dat' u 1:2 w lines
```

Comment: What is the first column and what is the second column? Do you want a fence plot or maybe a 3D-bar plot or something else? Have you checked this? https://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_5.4/fenceplot.html

Comment: The first (x) is time, the second (y) is volts.  I'm struggling to define the z column, so that I may create a fenceplot.

Comment: Why is the time not in increasing order? So, you want to create 3 fences? One for each separated block of data? Why do you think a fence plot is necessary if you simply can do a 2D plot: voltage versus time for 3 different measurements?